# Run DELETE query in trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm trying to run a `DELETE` and `UPDATE` query inside a trigger function in PL/pgSQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_delete_order_layer()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE index_ INTEGER;
DECLARE a RECORD;
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM map_layers_order WHERE id_map = OLD.id_map)
    THEN index_ := position FROM map_layers_order WHERE id_map = OLD.id_map AND id_layer = OLD.id_layer AND layer_type = 'layer';
    ELSE index_ := 0;
    END IF;
    RAISE NOTICE 'max_index % % %', index_, OLD.id_map, OLD.id_layer;
    EXECUTE 'DELETE FROM map_layers_order WHERE id_map = $1 AND id_layer = $2 AND layer_type = $3' USING OLD.id_map, OLD.id_layer, 'layer';
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE map_layers_order SET position = position -1 WHERE id_map = $1 AND position > $2' USING OLD.id_map, index_;
    VALUES (OLD.id_map, OLD.id_layer, 'layer', index_);
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I don't know why i'm getting this error in the line where it runs the DELETE query:

> Query has no destination for result data

Why is this error happen and how can I solve this? 
Obviously if I use `EXECUTE...INTO`, I get a more reasonable error saying that the query has no result.

Comment: Why are you using `execute`?  Dynamic SQL seems unnecessary for these operations.

Comment: `VALUES (OLD.id_map, OLD.id_layer, 'layer', index_);` - what this statement means?

Comment: ´index_ := position FROM` should be `select position into index_ from ...`. See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW The dynamic SQL is indeed totally useless and the final `values (..)` makes no sense at all

Comment: All you are right! Sorry! It was the part of `VALUES()` as @Abelisto said. I was reusing code and forget get ride of this part, and for this I made some changes to see what happened (like the execute). Now I get ride of all of this and I get this running. Thank you all.